# row.to_frame().T responds differently when passed to parallel processing

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a process that iterates over a pandas dataframe using by row, does some work, and spits out results.

```
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        os.chdir(outputdir)
        rowdf = row.to_frame().T
        points =[[rowdf.iloc[0].id,rowdf.iloc[0].start_location_long, rowdf.iloc[0].start_location_lat],[rowdf.iloc[0].id,rowdf.iloc[0].end_location_long, rowdf.iloc[0].end_location_lat]]
        pgdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(pd.DataFrame(points, columns =['id', 'longitude', 'latitude']), geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(pd.DataFrame(points, columns =['id', 'longitude', 'latitude']).longitude, pd.DataFrame(points, columns =['id', 'longitude', 'latitude']).latitude), crs=4326).to_crs('esri:102001')
        area = buffer(pgdf)
        area['id']=rowdf.iloc[0].id
        area.to_crs(4326).to_file(str(year) + '.gpkg', driver='GPKG', layer=str(rowdf.iloc[0].id)+'_area')
        make_line(pgdf, 'id').to_crs(4326).to_file(str(year) + '.gpkg', driver='GPKG', layer=str(rowdf.iloc[0].id)+'_plot')
        try:
            pass
            map_event(rowdf)
        except Exception as e:
            error_list.append([str(row.iloc[0].id),str(e)])
```

This runs outputting a polygon, a linesegment, and a linestring if map_event(rowdf) is successful.
When I rewrite it to

```
def task(row):
    rowdf = row.to_frame().T
        points =[[rowdf.iloc[0].id,rowdf.iloc[0].start_location_long, rowdf.iloc[0].start_location_lat],[rowdf.iloc[0].id,rowdf.iloc[0].end_location_long, rowdf.iloc[0].end_location_lat]]
        pgdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(pd.DataFrame(points, columns =['id', 'longitude', 'latitude']), geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(pd.DataFrame(points, columns =['id', 'longitude', 'latitude']).longitude, pd.DataFrame(points, columns =['id', 'longitude', 'latitude']).latitude), crs=4326).to_crs('esri:102001')
        area = buffer(pgdf)
        area['id']=rowdf.iloc[0].id
        area.to_crs(4326).to_file(str(year) + '.gpkg', driver='GPKG', layer=str(rowdf.iloc[0].id)+'_area')
        make_line(pgdf, 'id').to_crs(4326).to_file(str(year) + '.gpkg', driver='GPKG', layer=str(rowdf.iloc[0].id)+'_plot')
    try:
        pass
        map_event(rowdf)
    except Exception as e:
        error_list.append([str(row.iloc[0].id),str(e)])
```

and pass it to a multiprocessing pool with

```
    try:
        os.chdir(outputdir)
        with Pool(os.cpu_count()-4) as pool:
            for results in pool.map(task, df.iterrows()):
                pass
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

my row can no longer be returned transposed and set to a df, I get the error 'tuple' object has no attribute 'to_frame'

What is causing the behavior change for the line rowdf = row.to_frame().T between single and parallel processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df.iterrows()` will pass tuple of `index` and `row` to the `task`. From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html):

> **DataFrame.iterrows()**
> Iterate over DataFrame rows as `(index, Series)` pairs.

so change `task` accordingly:

```py
def task(data):
    (index, row) = data
    # ... use row
```